# Sort views in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, random, nsmutablearray, sorting

I am using a NSMutableArray to get all the subViews of a specific superView, everything works, but the log says:

```
superView contains (
"<UIView: 0x68795c0; frame = (20 172; 238 115); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x689aad0>>",
"<UIView: 0x6e67d90; frame = (143 295; 115 115); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e67dc0>>",
"<UIView: 0x6e6f1a0; frame = (20 49; 115 115); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e6e830>>",
"<UIView: 0x6e6fac0; frame = (143 49; 115 115); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e6faf0>>"
)
```

As you can see, it appears that the views are loaded randomly into the array, but it is important for me that they are loaded in order, so it loads the views from top to bottom of the superview. So it *should* look like this:

```
superView contains (
"<UIView: 0x6e6f1a0; frame = (20 49; 115 115); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e6e830>>",
"<UIView: 0x6e6fac0; frame = (143 49; 115 115); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e6faf0>>"
"<UIView: 0x68795c0; frame = (20 172; 238 115); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x689aad0>>",
"<UIView: 0x6e67d90; frame = (143 295; 115 115); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e67dc0>>",
)
```

Can anyone give me suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean they should be loaded "in order"?  Which property or key are you needing to sort on?

Comment: @Carter Sorry for the confusion, by 'in order' I mean that the array should be loading those views from top to bottom of the screen, so that views with a x coordinate of 0, for example, come first and the ones with 480 come last

Comment: The answers below describe how to sort an array, but an important note here is that `subviews` is not random. It's in z-order, which is the order of drawing so that views stack correctly. What you're asking for is y-order, which may be useful for your purposes but is meaningless for drawing.

Answer (score 0):

[sortedArraySortedUsingFunction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingFunction%3acontext%3a)

Answer (score 0):

NSArray has a variety of sorting methods; they generally involve having an additional function or method that takes one object as an argument and returns a type of `NSComparisonResult`. From the docs:

> A selector that identifies the method to use to compare two elements
>   at a time. The method should return `NSOrderedAscending` if the
>   receiving array is smaller than the argument, `NSOrderedDescending` if
>   the receiving array is larger than the argument, and `NSOrderedSame` if
>   they are equal.

You specify the actual comparison parameter.